# Extrema on a given set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Could you tell me if my approach to finding extrema on a set is good?

Let's take a function $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ and a set $N= \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 \le z \le 1 \} = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 \le z, \  z \le 1\}$.

I know how to look for extrema when the constraint is given by an equation, but I don't know what to do in situations like this one.

I guess we could try to draw this set and then somehow decide if there can or can't be any extrema there.

But I don't know what to do exactly.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: May be the function is $x+y+z$?

Comment: use Lagrange method

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx

Comment: @kmitov Of course, you are right. I'll corect that right now.

Comment: @datodatuashvili So first we check when the first partial derivatives are zero and if they satisfy the given inequalities. Next we take care of the boundaries (using Lagrange multipliers) and check the function's values at these points?

Comment: to be honest  i wanted to check  if largange works for inequality,it works when constraint is some fixed number

Comment: Could you explain that? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: May be you can also consider the $N$ is a cone which is a convex set

Comment: So this means that the function's extrema must lie on the set's boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_x=1, f_y=1, f_z=1$ So the system of the first derivatives does not have solution. There is no critical point.

Lagrange function is then
$F(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=x+y+z-\lambda(x^2+y^2-z)-\mu(z-1)$

$F_x=1-2x\lambda=0$

$F_y=1-2y\lambda=0$

$F_z=1+\lambda-\mu=0$

$F_\lambda=-x^2-y^2+z=0$

$F_\mu = 1-z=0$

The solutions of the system are $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 1)$ and 
 $(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 1)$

The first point gives maximum $=\sqrt{2}+1$, the second gives minimum $=1-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thank you. So if the first derivatives aren't zero, it suffices to solve the system of Lagrange function's first derivatives = 0?

Comment: Yes because the function f does not have critical points at all, therefore it does not have critical points inside the region described by the inequalities. Then we have to look for extreme values on the surface.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what 
I wanted to hear. Thanks :)